# Mathematics of password cracking

Tags: combinatorics, computer-science

**Background :** This is for a $6^{th}$ grade science project. I am doing a project on password cracking and I have created a program to predict how long your password would take to crack and then try to crack it. I have come up with an equation for how to predict how long it would take to crack your password but it always predicts way longer than it actually is. *(Passwords can only be lowercase letters and digits, so therefore Total Possible Combination is $36$).*

Password length for example will be $8$, and calculations per second will be $\boxed{cps=4\times10^9}$ ($4$ billion calculation per second)
My algorithm is
$\boxed{comb =36^8}\\\boxed{seconds=comb\div cps}$

What is wrong with my math here?

**EDIT:** I have realized that for where you enter calculations per second I was just using the default, which I had put in a variable to be "$4,000,000,000$" which isn't supported in the language I was using (You have to put "$4000000000$" without the commas)

Comment: Spaces are `\,` or `\;`. Your formula looks correct, so if it overestimates then the obvious question is: why do you think it does 4 billion calculations per second? Edit: wait, I may have it. Does your program exit early when it finds the password? Your calculation is the worst case: if the password is generated uniformly and randomly then on average it will take half that time.

Comment: Why do you think the results are too big? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

Combinations = $36^8 \approx 2.8 \times 10^{12}$

Seconds = $2.8 \times 10^{12} / 4 \times 10^9 = 700$ seconds.

If you are getting about $700$ seconds, then there's nothing wrong with your equations. Perhaps you are underestimating in your head how many combinations there are.